# How do I add a reusable block to a programmatically created post?

Tags: posts, block-editor

I am using WordPress for documenting a project. To lighten the workload, I plan to run a script to build a big old index of things. For example, "files that call function_x", or "files with @todo in them" - that sort of thing. Each of these will have a post made for them.

I have already created a set of reusable blocks that should be added to posts that are incomplete or automatically added (among other things). What I cannot figure out is how to add a known reusable block to a post when creating it in code.

How do I programmatically add a reusable block to a post?

Comment: have you tried adding the HTML comment with the ID swapped out for the reusable block you prefer?

Comment: No, but that sounds like it might work.